# Typescript overriding extended property within constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having an issue with Typescript where I extend a class and override a property from the super, however the super class property is still read in the constructor when I instantiate the sub class. Please see the below example:

```
class Person {

    public type:string = 'Generic Person';

    public constructor() {
        console.log(this.type);
    }

}

class Clown extends Person {

    public type:string = 'Scary Clown';

}

var person = new Person(), // 'Generic Person'
    clown = new Clown(); // 'Generic Person'

console.log(person.type); // 'Generic Person'
console.log(clown.type); // 'Scary Clown'
```

My expected behaviour would be 'Scary Clown' when I instantiate an instance of Clown. Is there another way I can achieve this without passing the values into the constructor itself or having some sort of init method that I fire manually after instantiating?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Property initializers are inserted right at the top of the constructor *before* the manually entered body of the constructor. So

```
class Person {
    public type:string = 'Generic Person';
    public constructor() {
        console.log(this.type);
    }
}
```

Becomes

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
        this.type = 'Generic Person';
        // NOTE: You want a different value for `type`
        console.log(this.type);
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

As you can see there is *no way* to get a different `type` in the parent constructor body using a property initializer.

Alternatively don't use `type` and rely on built-in `constructor` property:

```
interface Function{name?:string;}

class Person {    
    public constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}

class Clown extends Person {    
}

var person = new Person(), // 'Person'
    clown = new Clown(); // 'Clown'

console.log(person.constructor.name); // 'Person'
console.log(clown.constructor.name); // 'Clown'
```

Comment: Thanks Basarat. This works in the case where the property is the same as the class name however in other instances that won't work. But as you mentioned, the way that it currently works it's not possible.

Comment: Note that if you minify your code (which you should) this.constructor.name will become something like "n"